# "not as well educated as..." vs "Not so well educated as..."

Tags: word-choice, essay, grammar

I am writing a scholarship essay and one of my sentences is:

> "Although both of my parents have bachelor’s degrees now, they were not **as** well educated or stably employed when I was growing up."

When I asked someone to read it over, they suggested that I use *so* instead of *as*. I looked it up, and I found that generally negative comparisons use *so*, so it would be correct in this context. Since both *so* and *as* could work, which is more grammatically correct?

Comment: Might this question be more suited for English Language stack exchange or English Language Learners stack exchange as it is about what words one should use in a sentence, and not really about the writing itself?

Comment: Fair enough- I thought I'd post it here because I am a native speaker (I know the username is misleading, sorry) and this question pertained to a writing assignment, but I will post it somewhere else.

Comment: That is fine, but usually this site is for users who want help with their writing as a whole, and not just the choice of words that they use. (Hence why I recommended posting this question on English stack exchange.

Answer (score 2):

### English IS confusing...

... but it also has a hundred ways to do everything, at least half of which are technically correct. I'd state this completely differently, but maybe that won't fit your needs. I'd likely go with something more like:

> Today, my parents have bachelor's degrees and stable employment. When I was growing up, however, it was a very different story.

Then I'd go into an explanation of how things were different. Your first sentence doesn't have much emotional impact and comes off kind of impersonal. Usually if you're trying to get a scholarship, you are either trying to wow them with your technical knowledge and competence and/or make an emotional impact so they want you to have the scholarship. Don't use these exact words, but try for a more emotional, story-driven statement that evokes sympathy while not coming off as pitiful. You want to achieve an "overcoming adversity" feel that says "life was hard and I'm a stronger candidate because of it."

Answer (score 0):

Ok so neither of them sound right. if you were to write ¨Not as educated as¨, that would be better. Hope this helps. Also keep Employed the way it is, Employment doesn't sound right either.

Comment: Someone recently flagged this as "not an answer", presumably because it's quite short and lacks explanation. I personally think this does answer the question, but would you be able to go into a little more detail as to why your suggestion is better than the OP's suggestions?

Comment: Sure. One minute